# iCloud share group of calendars?

Tags: ical, icloud, calendar, google-calendar

I've been using icalx.com to sync all my many calendars as a single group. When I turned on iCloud, all my calendar group structure completely disappeared and I see no way to re-add it. Is there any way (including workarounds using icalx or Google Calendar as an intermediary) to continue sharing all my calendars as a single group? It's a huge pain for people to set up 10+ subscriptions just to see my events, not to mention having to check and uncheck all 10 each time they want to see what I'm doing.

Comment: I had to totally re-vamp how I used iCal when I moved MobileMe to the CalDAV servers. It was a big disruption and I decided to track far fewer calendars due to the hassle.

Comment: If I could just use some form of colour coding within one calendar this wouldn't be an issue for me *sigh*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When MobileMe upgraded calendars - it removed the group option. iCloud does not have a folder/group data structure.

[BusyCal](http://www.busymac.com/) does let you create groups to manage your local view of iCloud (and other) calendars, but doesn't change iCloud's limitation to not have those groups appear on the server end of things.

Their blog is an excellent source to get clear and well prepared discussion on the changes MobileMe has made as well as how iCloud is different.

Comment: I turned it off and went back to my humble local calendars.